# Entity framework core many to many unable to determine relationship

Tags: c#, orm, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I'm kinda stuck on a pretty simple problem.

I followed the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#other-relationship-patterns) to configure my many to many relationship but it does not work.

When I run the command to add a migration I get this error.

> ***Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation property 'Command.Platforms' of type 'ICollection'. Either
> manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
> '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
> 'OnModelCreating'.***

Do you know how to configure a many to many relationship without having to specify explicitly the joint table ?

Thanks for your answers.

These are the classes I want to configure with entity framework core.
The classes I want to perform many to many relation are Command and Platform.
Don't take Parameters into account.

**Command** class :

```
    public class Command
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int CommandId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(250)]
        public string Example { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }

        public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }
    }
```

**Platform** class:

```
    public class Platform
    {
        [Key]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public int PlatformId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Command> Commands { get; set; }
    }
```

My **DbContext** class:

```
    public class CommandsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommandsDbContext(DbContextOptions<CommandsDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Command> Commands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Parameter> CommandParameters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
    }
```

**EDIT :**
Ok I just found out it will only be available in EF core 5.
https://youtu.be/W1sxepfIMRM?t=751

Comment: Well, you could opt. for explicit, as described [here](https://www.edgesidesolutions.com/many-to-many-relationship-entity-framework-core/), but, I would thought this would work. You could try, btw, to enable lazy loading by making the ICollections `virtual`. It won't solve your problem, but it might be a little more eficient.

Comment: Hello Stefan, I understand that the problem could be solved but I just wanted know if there was a way to directly access the other table without having to play with the joint table.

Answer (score 0):

You have add to class Platform a property CommandId as a foreign key of Command class

Comment: Yes, because you have to add some code db context after this.Something like this  entity.HasOne(d => d.Command)
                    .WithMany(p => p.CommandPermissions)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CommanId)

Comment: The easiest way is to create a DB at first. After this use tools to generate code-firs EF.

Comment: Adding the property as suggested will create a one-2-many relation imo.